My custom useFetch hook does not retrieve 2 types of differents bodies
First of all I will say with React Im a begginer and what I really dont understand is why I cannot fetch 2 endpoints, so they retrieve me data and then I can use it in my differents components
This is my App.jsx
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import useFetch from './hooks/useFetch';
import { BlogContentPage, Homepage } from './pages';
import AboutPage from './pages/AboutPage';

export default function App() {
  let { loading, data, error } = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/blogs?populate=*'); // this one is ok, is recieving data.
  let { data: authors } = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/authors?populate=*'); // this one is not, and if I remove the one above this one works (!?!?!)
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;
  console.log(authors); // this is null..
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Homepage blogs={data ? data : ''} />}></Route>
        <Route path='/blog/:id' element={<BlogContentPage blogs={data ? data : ''} />}></Route>
        <Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage authors={authors ? authors : ''} />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

This is my useFetch custom Hook (and probably I'm doing something wrong here)..
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const json = await res.json();
        setData(json);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { loading, error, data };
};

export default useFetch;

My expectation was that the useFetch hook that I wrote work everytime it gets call.

When using 2 useFetch hook calls and the second one doesn't work.... what specifically isn't working? Can you provide any error/debugging/etc details about the specific problem?

Try to pass the first loading value, to the other fetch hook:
let { loading, data, error } = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/blogs?populate=*', false) <-- also add this
let { data: authors } = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/authors?populate=*', loading) // <-- from the first useFetch hook

and then inside the useFetch hook:
 useEffect(() => {if (!loading) {
const fetchAuthors = async () => {
  const { data: authorsData } = await useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/authors?populate=*');
  setAuthors(authorsData);
};
fetchAuthors();}}, [loading,url]);


What does the loading/fetching in one function have to do with loading/fetching in the other function? Can you clarify how you believe this solves OP's problem?

I just found the error and it was that I did not pass the loading and the error to the second API call and did not check if the second call was done successfully.
const {
loading: blogLoading,
data: blogs,
error: blogError,
} = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/blogs?populate=');
const {
loading: authorLoading,
data: authors,
error: authorError,
} = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/authors?populate=');
if (blogLoading || authorLoading) return Loading...;
if (blogError || authorError) return Error!;
I appreciate all the effort that folks made, and I apologize for not looking a little bit more at the error, I come from Java and IntelliJ and the IDEs facilitate a little bit more the debug of the app..

Well you could just refactor you custom hook to accept multiple endpoints
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useFetch = (urls) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const promises = urls.map(async (url) => {
          const res = await fetch(url);
          return res.json();
        });
        const results = await Promise.all(promises);
        setData(results);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [urls]);

  return { loading, error, data };
};

export default useFetch;

And in your main file you can use it this way
  const { loading, data: blogData, error } = useFetch(['http://localhost:1337/api/blogs?populate=*', 'http://localhost:1337/api/authors?populate=*']);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

